# chartjs, How to access x-axis, which is generated dynamically by pushing {x,y} in datasets.data[] in chartjs Scatter plot or Line plot repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am plotting a multi-axis scatter plot in which first `datasets[0]` I have plotted nominal data that is static then I am pushing in second `datasets[1]` dynamic generated `dataPoint{x,y}`.
How to access the dynamically generated x-axis after pushing dynamic `dataPoint={x,y}` in `mychart.config.data.datasets[0].data.push(dataPoint)`, I want to set some scale property of x-axis that is dynamically generated when I pushed some data point, before any data point when `datasets[0].data` is empty there is no x-axis but when I pushed some data, chartjs dynamically generate x-axis and its range.

```
var myOptions = {

scales: {
        xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    offsetGridLines: false
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'x-axis-2',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                display: false,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'x values',
                    fontSize: 10

                },
                ticks: {
                    max: myMax,
                    min: myMin,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

var myDataset = {
    type: 'scatter',
    lineTension: 0,
    fill: false,
    data: myData,
};

var config = {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: myDataset,
    },
    options: myOptions
};
```

// this configuration is only for the static dataset means this xAxes config shall work only if all dataPoints will be pushed at once.

```
xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    offsetGridLines: false
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'x-axis-2',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                display: false,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'x values',
                    fontSize: 10

                },
                ticks: {
                    max: myMax,
                    min: myMin,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                }
            }
        ]
```

But how to access another x-axis that is being generated by chartjs dynamically when pushing dataPoint one by one?

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
   config.data.datasets[1].data.push({
        x: myX,
        y: myY
   });
   Chart.update();
}
```

Chart is being updated fine, but I can not access the X-Axis scale that is being dynamically generated by above for loop code.